# How to launch a daemon on RCP plugin load

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an RCP plugin and what to launch a java based service when it loads first time.
So please tell how should I do this. That is the java file that runs on the first launch.

Regards,
Levon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a new [startup](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_startup.html) `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension to the your RCP application then  create a class that implements `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup` and run a thread with using [Eclipse Jobs Api](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html).